# Is there a way to refer to a HQL subquery column?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, hql

I'd like to perform an HQL query (via Spring Data's `@Query`) which selects records from `message` that have value in field `a` matching the latest message's value, and also matching certain conditions on other fields.

The most obvious approach as I see it would be to use a subquery which maxes records by `createTime` field, groups them by `a` and then refer to this column from subquery. However, I can't create the HQL which would compile. Is there a way to refer to subquery's columns, or I should try a different approach to solve this problem?

HQL expression I tried to use:

```
select m from Message m where m.a = (
    select m2.a, max(m2.createTime) from Message m2
    where ... (additional conditions)
).a
```

Unfortunately, it threw `java.lang.NullPointerException` at a compile time.

Comment: This would be relatively easy with SQL. Do you really *have to* use HQL?

Comment: @LukasEder I know it would be fairly easy if I used SQL, but unfortunately, it's prohibited to use native queries in this particular project.

Comment: Do you know the reason why? You can still map the results of a native query to your `Message` entity...

Comment: @LukasEder Firstly, for versatility - in case we change the underlying DB implementations, native queries won't work (and this _is_ a possible case in the future). Secondly, for consistency, as we use HQL (but not native) queries all across the project.

Comment: For the first point, jOOQ could be an option (disclaimer, I work for the vendor). Other than that, what RDBMS are realistic targets for your project? Chances are, this can still be done quite reasonably with "standard SQL". For the second point, not too sure what I can say to that :) Except: Why? Anyway. I don't think your kind of query is possible with HQL, let alone in a way that will perform well...

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but in HQL you can use the row value comparison operator, so you should be ablte to do the following `select m from Message m where (m.a, m.createTime) = (select m2.a, max(m2.createTime) from Message m2 where ... (additional conditions) )`

Comment: @ChristianBeikov: You'd have to use `IN`, not `=`, and the subquery would need a `GROUP BY` clause, of course. A variety of RDBMS doesn't support this syntax, though. Does Hibernate emulate it correctly using `EXISTS`, e.g. for MS Access, DB2, Derby, Firebird, Hana, Ingres, SQL Server, SQLite, Sybase?

Comment: Not sure about the specifics, I just wanted to showcase that row value comparison can help. Hibernate just passes that through AFAIK, there is no emulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical top N per category query (where `N = 1` in your case):

```sql
SELECT m
FROM Message m 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  FROM Message m2
  WHERE m2.a = m.a
  AND m2.createTime > m.createTime
)
```

In other words, find all messages for which there doesn't exist a more recent message in the same "category" `m.a`.

Unfortunately, HQL (at least as of Hibernate 5, maybe 6 has better options) doesn't seem to offer a much better approach than self-anti joining the message table here, which is quite likely to produce bad performance for large tables, even with an index on `(a, create_time)`. If this turns out to be a problem, you can still try a SQL solution. Depending on your RDBMS, you should be able to do this with a single access to the message table.

Comment: That query solves my problem. It's sad that HQL has neither `limit` keyword nor subquery parameter reference - any of these would make life easier :( Nevertheless, thanks for the thorough explanation!

Comment: @IvanKozin: You know what would make your life easier...? Using SQL ;-) OK, I'm outta here, was worth trying to convince you.